# Magento pro-grammatically save telephone number

Tags: magento-1.9, php, customer

I have inserted the customer data in Magento(1.9) pro-grammatically,in my custom table.But the telephone number is not get inserted

```
My data:
Array
(
    [firstname] => Marc L
    [lastname] => Kruger
    [email] => mkruger@morrisonfenske.com
    [street] => 5125 County Road 101, Suite 102
    [city] => Minnetonka
    [state] => MN
    [country] => US
    [telephone] => 952-975-0050
)
$csv = Mage::getModel('flsearch/csv');
$csv->setData($customer)->save()
```

Comment: but in the array you printed it shows telephone number.

Comment: make sure you you have the column `telephone` in your table, that has the type `varchar` or `text`. If that's ok. Clear the cache. Maybe you added the phone column later and the table schema is still cached. This happens even if your cache is disabled.

Comment: @Marius : thanks for your answer, after clear the catch its working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments...

make sure you you have the column telephone in your table, that has the type `varchar` or `text`. If that's OK, clear the cache. Maybe you added the phone column later and the table schema is still cached. This happens even if your cache is disabled.